# how to add markup to text using JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I need to add markup to some text using JavaScript regular expressions. In Python I could do this with:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('(banana|apple)', r'<b>\1</b>', 'I have 1 banana and 2 apples!')
'I have 1 <b>banana</b> and 2 <b>apple</b>s!'
```

What is the equivalent in JavaScript?
string.replace(regex, newstring) seems to only take a raw string for replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new string, you can reference capture groups via the tokens `$1`, `$2`, etc. A lot of the high-level reference sites (like w3schools) fail to document that. It's in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), of course, or more accessibly discussed [on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace).

So taking your example:

```
"I have 1 banana and 2 apples!".replace(/(banana|apple)/gi, "<b>$1</b>");
```

(Of course, the "s" in "apples" won't be inside the tag...)  I used the 'i' flag there assuming you want to process "Banana" and "Apple" as well as "banana" and "apple".

Comment: @Richard: Glad to help. Amusingly, I was surprised when I ran across this feature of #replace...because I, too, had been working from the w3schools pages. :-) Those pages are useful, but really *really* incomplete, so I work from the spec and MDC a lot more now.

Comment: wow the Mozilla JavaScript documentation is so detailed! - I will have to get into the habit of checking there first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace) for this and use `$n` to reference captured groups from the regular expression:

```
var in = 'I have 1 banana and 2 apples!';
var out = in.replace(/(banana|apple)/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```